# ¿Error 404 al cargar imágenes usando asset en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Cordial saludo compañeros, presento el siguiente problema resulta que en mi aplicacion, guardo imágenes en la carpeta storage/app/public/fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

use el comando php artisan storage:link para vincularla, y en la vista muestro las imagenes de la siguiente manera:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$foto->url) }}" alt="">
```

En mi pc personal funciona bien, y me muestra las imágenes, el problema es que al copiar el proyecto a otro pc, ya no me cargan las imágenes y me muestra error 404:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Utilizo laragon para trabajar en local, no se si eso tenga algo que ver.

¿Que puede estar pasando aqui?

Comment: donde tienes , las imágenes en una subcarpeta  de storage  o en la carpeta public?

Comment: en una subcarpeta de storage llamada fotos

Comment: Edite la pregunta y le agregue la imagen de la carpeta donde guardo las fotos.

Comment: y has probado poner `storage/app/public` ?

Comment: si, y sigue el mismo error.

Comment: Pero en mi pc personal me muestra las imagenes, no entiendo porque al copiar el proyecto y pasarlo a otro equipo sucede esto, en el otro pc tambien uso laragon para trabajar en local.

Comment: Despues de copiar el proyecto, ejecuta nuevamente `php artisan storage:link` en el destino

Comment: Me aparece un error que dice, The public/storage directory already link